# Notification destroying and creating existing activity

Tags: android

My notification is supposed to launch an activity or simply show the activity if it's already open (on screen). What the notification does instead is destroy the activity and then create it again, even if the activity is already on the screen.

I've searched for solutions, and they say to add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to the activity in the manifest, but this has no effect, the activity is still destroyed and recreated whenever the user clicks on the notification.

This is how the notification is told to start the activity on click:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MyActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = 
    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent); 
// mBuilder is NotificationCompat.Builder()
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace the line

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = 
stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

with

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

Comment: This is insane! And it does the job.

Comment: but the activity is recreate when clicked notification

Answer (score -1):

It cannot be. The documentation clearly "If an instance of the activity already exists at the top of the target task, the system routes the intent to that instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance of the activity." I have used this over and over again. Double check whether you have set `MyActivity` `launchMode` to `singleTop`

Comment: I have. Double-checked I mean. I wonder if it has something to do with messing with the TaskStackBuilder (it's on the Android dev site as a way to make the back button lead to the parent activity of the app the notification is opening)

Comment: I confirm this behavior exists, FFS, what's going on in Android as always. Previously singleTop worked just fine in Android